# Difference between Message Router and Content based Router in EIP

Tags: java, apache-camel, esb

I'd like to understand what exactly is the difference between the two [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html)

[Content-Based Router](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html)

[Message Router](http://camel.apache.org/message-router.html)

The definition at camel documentation is suggestive that Content-Based router is a special case of Message Router. They why list them separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually "Message Router" is one of the "Basic Messaging Concepts". List of such basic messaging concepts is:

- Channel - Messaging applications transmit data through a Message Channel, a virtual pipe that connects a sender to a receiver.
- Message - A Message is an atomic packet of data that can be transmitted on a channel.
- Multi-step delivery - Set of actions often need to be performed on the message after it is sent by its original sender but before it is received by its final receiver.
- Routing - In a large enterprise with numerous applications and channels to connect them, a message may have to go through several channels to reach its final destination. The route a message must follow may be so complex that the original sender does not know what channel will get the message to the final receiver. Instead, the original sender sends the message to a Message Router.
- Transformation - Various applications may not agree on the format for the same conceptual data; the sender formats the message one way, yet the receiver expects it to be formatted another way.
- Endpoint - An application does not have some built-in capability to interface with a messaging system. Rather, it must contain a layer of code that knows both how the application works and how the messaging system works, bridging the two so that they work together.

"Content Based Router" is one of the "Message Routers" and there are a lot of different other Message Routers available like "Message Filter", "Splitter", "Aggregator", "Recipient list" etc.

I suggest reading a book that used by camel so all such points will be more clear: 
https://www.amazon.com/o/asin/0321200683/ref=nosim/enterpriseint-20

Comment: Indeed, that is what I initially understood, going by the verbal meaning "Message Router" since in a message oriented Integration framework, everything is a message, so a message router could be anything that routes messages. Going by the examples you put, "Message Router" would be a rather abstract term and as-such not a pattern in itself. But i do get the point. However since my question arose from Camel's implementation, i'd like to see what they make of it

Comment: Actually in camel we can see information about integration patterns http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html and Message Router is in the section related for overall messaging. But example is completely the same as for content based routing to simplify understanding as "content-based routing" is probably most often used message routing. But then camel doc has specific section "Message Routing" which listed all remaining routing patterns.

Comment: yes, the camel documentation indeed matches the EIP book. Both of them  fail to identify the HIERARCHY. maybe it would not be so confusing if they simply created sub-sections

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the patterns Message Router only applies when the input and output is a queue or topic of a messaging system.

Content-based Router is not limited to messaging. I think you can say that inside a Message Router you have a Content-based router that decides which way to go.

In camel the decision is made using the choice() element.

If my assumption is correct then the documentation of the [Message-Router at camel](http://camel.apache.org/message-router.html) is wrong as it does not reflect the queues. I will check with the camel dev list and correct the wiki page if we agree on this.

Comment: This means message router is a special case of Content-based router? If so, is it really required to identify Message Router as a dedicated pattern

Comment: Good question... I also think it is a bit redundant.